# MySQL pagination. Check if last record is reached

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, limit, offset

I am trying to implement pagination using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` with MySQL. On each database query, I would like to check if the last record within the table is reached. What is the best approach on this? Should I use another query for `COUNT` and then compare it with the `OFFSET`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sql_calc_found_rows`, which makes MySQL calculate how many rows would have been returned if there had been no limit:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT x,y
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then you can use

```
SELECT found_rows();
```

to retrieve that count. It's still two separate query calls, but the found_rows() call is very cheap, because the heavy lifting was already done by the main `SELECT`.

You can do two separate queries with a `COUNT()`, but then you're replicating work and throwing away most of it.

Comment: I've been getting the row count by using COUNT(*) while dropping the fields and limit clause while keeping the joins and where clauses in tact. A cursory search of the term SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS shows that the question of using ONE versus TWO queries being better/faster or not is best answered by "depends" (sigh). Might not hurt to do timing tests and compare each method depending on how large/complex your schema, dataset and where clauses are.